# In an ExtJS custom renderer how do I tell if the column header has been clicked?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have an ExtJs EditorGridPanel with a custom renderer.  The basic idea is to display a checkbox when an item needs to be registered and the text Registered when an item is already registered.  Everything is working swimmingly except for when clicking on the header, the entire grid re-renders and every cell toggles.  Furthermore, the sort does not work.  How to I tell when the header has been clicked so that all my checkboxes do not toggle?  How do I fix the sort for the column?  Right now it does not sort.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(
    {
    columns: [
        { id: 'ItemOid', header: "ItemOid", width: 100, sortable: true, locked: true, dataIndex: 'ItemOid', hidden: true },
        { id: 'nNumber', header: "N-#", width: 100, sortable: true, locked: true, dataIndex: 'NNumber' },
        { header: "Make", width: 150, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Make' },
        { header: "Model", width: 150, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Model' },
        { header: "Register",
            width: 55,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'Register',
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            renderer: renderFunction
        }
    ]
    });

function renderFunction(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

    if (!store.getAt(rowIndex).data['ItemNeedsRegistered'])
        return 'Registered';

    var isRegistered = store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Registered'];
    var renderString;

    if (initialItemRender || isRegistered) {
        renderString = '<input type="checkbox" id="chkRegistered' + rowIndex + '" />';
        store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Registered'] = false;
    } else {
        renderString = '<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" id="chkRegistered' + rowIndex + '" />';
        store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Registered'] = true;
    }

    return renderString;
}

var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        store: itemStore,
        cm: colModel,
        sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({ singleSelect: true }),
        viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true
        },
        height: 100,
        split: true,
        region: 'north'
    });
```

Here is my second attempt that also fails, by trying to update the underlying value and it does not check or uncheck.

```
function renderFunction(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

    if (!store.getAt(rowIndex).data['ItemNeedsRegistered'])
        return 'Registered';

    var isRegistered = store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Registered'];
    var renderString;

    if (initialItemRender || !isRegistered) {
        renderString = '<input type="checkbox" id="chkRegistered' + rowIndex + '"' 
        + ' onClick="updateStoreOnClick(' + rowIndex + ', true);"'
        + ' />';
    } else {
        renderString = '<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" id="chkRegistered' + rowIndex + '"'
        + ' onClick="updateStoreOnClick(' + rowIndex + ', false);"'                
        + ' />';
    }

    return renderString;
}

function updateStoreOnClick(rowIndex, value) {
    store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Registered'] = value;
}
```

Comment: Where is `initialItemRender` being defined?

Comment: initialItemRender is set to true and then after the store load it is set to false

Comment: Okay. Did you get a chance to try my suggestions below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a custom check column:

```
    //#region Custom Check Column
    AVRMS.AircraftRegisterCheckColumn = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.Column, {
    /**
        * @private
        * Process and refire events routed from the GridView's processEvent method.
        */
        processEvent: function(name, e, grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            if (name == 'mousedown') {
                var record = grid.store.getAt(rowIndex);

                if (grid.store.getAt(rowIndex).data['AircraftNeedsRegistered'])
                    record.set(this.dataIndex, !record.data[this.dataIndex]);

                return false; // Cancel row selection.
            } else {
                return Ext.grid.ActionColumn.superclass.processEvent.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },

        renderer: function(v, p, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            if (!store.getAt(rowIndex).data['AircraftNeedsRegistered'])
                return store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Status'];

            p.css += ' x-grid3-check-col-td';
            return String.format('<div class="x-grid3-check-col{0}">&#160;</div>', v ? '-on' : '');
        },

        // Deprecate use as a plugin. Remove in 4.0
        init: Ext.emptyFn
    });

    Ext.reg('airRegChkCol', AVRMS.AircraftRegisterCheckColumn);

    // register ptype. Deprecate. Remove in 4.0
    Ext.preg('airRegChkCol', AVRMS.AircraftRegisterCheckColumn);

    // register Column xtype
    Ext.grid.Column.types.airRegChkCol = AVRMS.AircraftRegisterCheckColumn;

    //#endregion

//#region ColumnModel
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(
    {
        columns: [
            { id: 'AircraftOid', header: "AircraftOid", width: 100, sortable: true, locked: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'AircraftOid', hidden: true, menuDisabled: true },
            { id: 'nNumber', header: "N-Number", width: 75, sortable: true, locked: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'NNumber', menuDisabled: true },
            { header: "Make", width: 150, sortable: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'Make', menuDisabled: true },
            { header: "Model", width: 150, sortable: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'Model', menuDisabled: true },
            {
                header: "Airworthy",
                width: 75,
                sortable: true,
                hideable: false,
                dataIndex: 'Airworthy',
                menuDisabled: true,
                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                    if (value == true)
                        return 'Yes';
                    return 'No';
                },
                editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                    id: 'makeCombo',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    store: airworthy,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    forceSelection: true,
                    mode: 'local',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    selectOnFocus: true,
                    lazyRender: true,
                    listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
                })
            },
            {
                id: 'Register',
                header: "Select to Register",
                width: 75,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'Register',
                xtype: 'airRegChkCol',
                hideable: false,
                menuDisabled: true
            }]
    });


//#endregion

//#region grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: aircraftStore,
    cm: colModel,
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({ singleSelect: true }),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    height: 100,
    split: true,
    region: 'north'
});
//#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

The toggling problem is occurring because you're directly updating each record's `Registered` attribute during the render. The next time you cause a render of the grid (e.g., when sorting), the values of all the records' `Registered` attributes are the boolean opposite of what they were to begin with. You probably shouldn't be changing those attributes during render, but instead find a way to get the correct value from the checkbox just before saving.

For sorting, you can manually create a numeric attribute on your record that contains a semi-arbitrary value specifically for sorting. For example, call the attribute `RegisteredSort` and give it these values:

- 1 — items not requiring registration
- 2 — registered items
- 3 — unregistered items

Then you use the `RegisteredSort` attribute as the `dataIndex` for that column rather than `Registered`.

Comment: I realize that the sort is causing a re-render.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to capture the click event of the checkbox to change the underlying value.  I put in an onclick event and it never fires.

Comment: Can you update your original question with the code you're using to attach the `onclick` handler?

Comment: Without seeing the actual error message, I'm guessing the `store` variable in your `updateStoreOnClick` function is undefined. Try changing that to `itemStore` and see if that gets further. If it doesn't, please update the question with the JavaScript error message you're seeing.

Comment: I changed it to itemStore.  There is no error message in firebug, it just does nothing.

Comment: What are you *expecting* it to do? Post the data to the server? Re-render the grid? I think it's doing exactly what you tell it to do: update the value in the store, and that's all. Please be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, because it seems like this has crept outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: Brandan, sorry I am trying to update the store so that the grid will update as well.  Do I have to manually call Render somehow or call DataChanged or raise a data changed event?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the rowIndex will be 0 when you click on the header... How about adding

```
if(rowIndex == 0) return;
```

to the top of renderFunction?

Comment: For the render during the sort, it is looping through all the rows on the sort.

Comment: Ah, sorry, never worked with a custom renderer, just thought that might help. Apparently not. ;) Good luck!